# Is there a way to see the moderator agreement if you are not a moderator?

Tags: support, status-completed, moderators, legal

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74799/non-legalese-eula-for-diamonds/74810#74810) mentions the existence of a moderator agreement. Is there a way I can see it if I'm not a moderator? I'm just curious.

Maybe a mod can copy & paste it as an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We have made this public at [/legal/moderator-agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement)

Comment: Can I suggest including this link in /admin/links as well instead of me hunting it down to here?

Comment: That page says "Stack Exchange Inc." while the copy in the other answer says "Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc". Which one is correct?

Comment: @Nemo "Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc." was the old name of the company that operated the network; it later changed its name to "Stack Exchange, Inc.". The company couldn't legally be called "Stack Overflow" because there's another company registered with the same name, so it had to use that workaround early on, but once other network sites were created, it moved to a more "relevant" name that wasn't taken. (The later 2015 change to "Stack Overflow" was just a rebranding; the company still has the name "Stack Exchange, Inc." for this same reason.)

Answer (score 14):

Hopefully this is okay to post:

> In order to access the ♦ moderator functions, please review and accept the following terms:
>
> I acknowledge and agree that as a moderator for Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc.
>
> - I will abide by the then-current Terms of Service of Board and Card Games, and other moderator policies made available to me,
> - I acknowledge that I may have access to potentially personally-identifying information about Board and Card Games users and that in connection with such access
>
>   - I will use such information solely in accordance with the then-current Privacy Policy of Board and Card Games,
>   - I will not disclose this information to anyone,
>   - I will not store or copy this information and
>   - I will only use such information in connection with performance as a Board and Card Games moderator for the benefit of Board and Card Games.
>
> I acknowledge and agree that I am an independent volunteer moderator to Board and Card Games and I am not an employee, agent or representative of Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc., and I have no authority to bind Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc. in any manner. Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc. reserves the right to terminate my privileges as a moderator at any time without warning.

Comment: Yes, it's okay to post. The EULA says, essentially, that *"you have access to private information; don't share it."* ... No big trade secrets there.

Comment: ...As well as, you agree to perform thee services without compensation.