# Evaluating the risks of allowing teen moderators on the SE network

Tags: discussion, moderation, account-suspension

I have a David vs Goliath case here involving a teen moderator on Stack Overflow. His display name is **[BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock)**.

I'm a low reputation SO user (less than 150 points) who was recently suspended for **Voting Irregularities** by BoltClock. Eventually the mistake was corrected by another non-teen moderator. Normally, you cannot argue with a moderator unless you have solid proof. Following is the proof in my case:

[image: mistake by teen moderator on SO]

Now back to our discussion. How come a moderator can suspend a user without any proof of wrongdoing? Could it be that BoltClock's **lack of experience** or **young age** is the factor for his mistake? What is the lesson from this mistake? Do we need to introduce a minimum age requirement for any future moderator on the SE network?

Comment: Or, you know, *we [fat-fingered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_finger) this one*

Comment: By making this about age you're going down a very non-constructive route, age just isn't important in this case. A moderator needs a certain maturity, but that is not strongly correlated with age in my experience. Moderators make mistakes, they are just humans (with some exceptions). We have excellent mods on the network that are still underage, I see no reason why we should stop them from becoming mods.

Comment: The mods here do a great job - but this is one of the "known issues" of being human.  It is not a bug :P  Even the highest ranking users here sometimes make mistakes - same as the new users... No need to take offence or point fingers...

Comment: How is blaming a mistake on a mod's age different than the mistake said mod made in this case?

Comment: Given that this was resolved several hours ago, it does seem to be counter productive to raise it here now.

Comment: The reason this has been down-voted so heavily is that the voters simply don't think an age limit is needed to be a mod. Voting on Meta works differently, but since this isn't your first Meta post, I'm sure you are aware of this.

Comment: @Karipap Yep, it's you against the world, buddy. But I'm not sure about the "fat finger" either, because it implies an accidental button press. I'm not a 100% sure about the process, but suspending a user for a specific reason with an accidental click sounds unlikely.

Comment: @Karipap Your **David vs Goliath** analogy is flawed.  David wins.

Comment: @C.Ross, unless he's referring to age, in which case, BoltClock is David. Of course, my first (and continuing) reaction to this "question" was - Are you freakin' kidding me?

Comment: moderators are helping moderators covering their mistakes. But doing so only will do harm to SE network. I believe my post is a valid point for discussion. Show to other normal users that meta is the place to discuss everything including moderators. It is shame that a moderator named casperone close this post with one vote.

Comment: I reopened it because it'd be a shame to see this go down so quickly. One day, I'll grow up...

Comment: *Yawn* Is there something of value here or can we close this again?  This got tired 15 seconds after it was posted.

Comment: @lunboks Why a valid concern? Are you aware of problems being generated by the moderator's age?

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes, no matter what their age. Anyways, I thought that these things were detected by the system, not by a person.

Comment: @CoffeeRain - Detected, yes, but a human has to take the action.

Comment: @Karipap Yes, yes, indeed I am.  Other shameless acts I'll perform are suspensions for people who are *extremely* rude when it's [codified in the site FAQ to **be nice**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#benice).  Seriously, we all have better things to do today.

Comment: @Karipap I don't think the volunteer moderator team is easily bullied by threats of complaining to their boss, either.  Especially when you compare their contributions to the contributions of the person doing the complaining.

Comment: @lunboks for the record, it takes like three or four button presses to suspend, and sends an email to several people, including all the people of note on the SE team.

Comment: Everybody's commented here, but this question bothered me enough that I had to chip in my two cents. I had seen BoltClock around the site for a good long while (well before he was elected moderator) before I found out what his age was. I have to say I was shocked, because he carried himself with greater maturity that someone twice or three times his age. I strongly endorsed him in the election because of this, and he's done a great job since then. Age plays no role here, and as far as experience goes, he's spent more time on this site than the vast majority of users.

Comment: I decided to undelete this, not so much because the answers are useful as for the sake of my own entertainment. Also, I turned 21 last month, so it's like a belated birthday present to myself or something.

Comment: @ChrisF re your comment "Given that this was resolved several hours ago, it does seem to be counter productive to raise it here now": The suspension had been resolved; the OP wanted to make sure nothing like that happened again. I don't see how it had been resolved hours before (or since). I agree with other commenters'/answerers' objections/answers to various parts of the question, but this comment of yours seems incorrect.

Comment: @msh210 The `resolved` comment is referring to the suspension, which was reversed before the original poster put the question up.

Answer (score 69):

Splitting hairs, but BoltClock isn't a teenager.  According to [his profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) he's 20.

Regardless of anyone's age, every single active moderator has made mistakes.  The more active we are, the more mistakes we make.  (The proportion stays about even, but it's a numbers game.)

> Now back to our discussion. How come a moderator can suspend a user without any proof of wrong doing?

At the very least I would rate your account history as an interesting read, so this is a far cry from a case "without any proof of wrong doing."

> Is it because BoltClock just **lack of experience** or **young age** is the factor for his mistake?

I doubt it.  After reading your reply BoltClock asked another moderator to double check his decision.  An immature person might have just ignored your response, or tried to bury it.  That clearly didn't happen here, since BoltClock asked other moderators for a second opinion.

> What is the lesson for this mistake? Do we need to introduce minimum age requirement for any future moderator on SE network?

I don't think that's necessary for several reasons:

1. When we elect moderators we look at their contributions to the site.  We can all decide based on their actions and writing whether or not we think they're mature enough to handle the responsibility.  The community can make that decision without taking age into account.
2. People can lie about their age on their profile.  You don't really know how old anyone is on here.
3. BoltClock is the youngest moderator on Stack Overflow, but he's not the least mature.  (Commence debating on who that is... ;))

Comment: "Splitting hairs, but BoltClock isn't a teenager. According to his profile he's 20." :)

Comment: [Youngest MOD](http://askubuntu.com/users/6005/jrg)?

Comment: @Lix Yes, that'd be me. However, I'm not on stackoverflow, and as such the *culture* is different.

Comment: @Lix ...on Stack Overflow.  I can't keep up with the whole network.  :)

Comment: LOL - :P  Just my $0.02 @jrg - you [learn something new](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/913660#913660) every day :P

Comment: "*but he's not the least mature.*"  ***HEY!!!***

Comment: *"every single active moderator has made mistakes"* Uhg. But haven't we.

Comment: I object to this answer implying I'm not infallible.

Comment: @dmckee right? Oy.

Comment: I think I'm the youngest mod (or pretty close) now. :P

Comment: @Luke Congratulations!  I think you are the youngest now, since [jrg](http://askubuntu.com/users/6005/jrg) turned 16.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Nope, it's [this guy](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/46/bryan-dunsmore)

Comment: @Manishearth So young he won't even fill in his birth date?  I won't ask, in case he'd be violating COPPA.  :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Nah, he's mentioned his age somewhere in public chat. Doesn't mean he wants it on his profile.

Comment: He's almost as old as Luke, but not quite.

Answer (score 43):

Every moderator is prone to mistakes, young or old. Everyone is also capable of maturity, teenage or adult. I do not believe that age is a factor that should be considered for a moderator. Note that revealing age isn't even required on the sites, so this really isn't even an enforceable metric to require of moderators. Moderators are required to sign a simple [EULA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74811/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-moderator-eula-if-you-are-not-a-moderator/74813#74813) which requires affirming the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) which requires the person to be of at least 13 years of age. Past that, we're good.

There are only two ways to be a moderator - you have to be handpicked by the Team, or you have to be elected by the community. This isn't a job that just anyone can get - people get this job through the merits of their contributions and activity on the site. We've both appointed and elected young moderators across the entire network, and they've proven to be as responsible and capable as the adult moderators, sometimes even shining *above* their older compatriots on the same sites. So, no, I don't think we should implement an age requirement, because we'd lose a number of very good moderators for reasons completely unrelated to their own ability to help us succeed as a network.

Answer (score 31):

Following your logic, we should probably screen all questions on meta from users with purple fractal gravatars because you have a purple gravatar and 100% of your meta questions have more than 20 downvotes!  Both your answers have negative scores, too.

The correlation is **FOUR TIMES AS STRONG** as that between the young moderator and making mistakes since it's happened four times as often, and with 100% consistency.

Comment: Fan-slam-tastic.

Comment: I have the spine to voice my opinions despite my poor command of English. Everyone know how to voice politically correct talks. I'm who I'm. Check your past answers and questions.

Comment: @Karipap I have checked my own.  I'm making a point that you are confusing **correlation** with **causation**.  Just because I shave every morning, and every morning the sun rises, does not mean that my shaving makes the sun rise.

Answer (score 16):

> Disclaimer: I myself am a teen, so this may be <s>a wee bit</s> biased

I really doubt that the reason for the mistake is that he was a teen. While most teens act immature, the mature ones have pretty much the same level of maturity as other adults, in my experience. You usually can't even tell the difference... A teen who's been elected a mod most certainly falls under this "mature" category, and wouldn't be any different from the other mods.

People make mistakes. So do mods. Note that the vote-detection system is internal, and mods can only see certain patterns. They cannot see who you voted against, just something or the other indicating "unusual voting patterns detected" (I'm not a mod so I don't know exactly what they see). In this case, I believe that the mod under scrutiny just saw the flag and maybe made a mistake in interpreting it/hit the button too quickly.

Also, BoltClock is 20 and I doubt that the concept of teenage immaturity, however flawed, even applies to him.

Comment: I'll just toss this up in the air, but from what I've seen, teens are as much of a grab bag as adults are - you might get crazy ones, you might get whiny ones, you might get anything else. Just being a "teen" means there is a stereotype that is being applied. *note: I'm biased as well, since I'm also a young moderator ([not on SO though](http://askubuntu.com/users/6005)).*

Comment: Yeah, the only major I see between teens and adults is that we can cut the teens some slack for lack of experience. Adults have no excuse.

Comment: @jrg exactly my point :)

Answer (score 14):

I've noticed a *ton* of other very high-rep SO users that are *much* younger than I am, and that would likely make much better mods than me. Age is not what makes one a good moderator.

As a metric, age *is* likely to have *some* correlation with one's skill at moderating a community, but the correlation is *definitely NOT* a uniform correlation because at various ages, one's ability will be different.

Much more important is *how the community sees the moderator in question*. If the community feels that the moderator is fair, just, a good leader, wields his/her power responsibly, and *makes the community better*, then the moderator is *doing a good job*. These "measuring sticks" are very much the same ones used in *most* governments around the world where leaders are elected by the citizens and, in general, it has proven to work *pretty well*, which is why moderators for the SE network are *elected*, and not just appointed.

Raising the concern is valid, and it is always good to have a discussion, but in this case, I don't believe you have much of a leg to stand on when it comes to supporting your argument that age is a factor in moderation ability. If anything, *time* matters *much* more.