# Is there a council of the elders?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, privileges, users, on-hold

When a question is put "on hold", I verified three or four times (when my answer was ready), most of the "close" voters seem to be rather older programmers. It's not that I'm interested, but I can see their names and I have already lost time with the answer. Is this a fact? Is up there a council of the elders?

Comment: It's true: http://i.imgur.com/P1zaUwb.png  You might be able to join, but No Homers allowed.

Comment: @asawyer Well I'm Bart, coming of age

Comment: @Random from ... "Ashley Judd": you can't have 32 since  Ashley Judd has 45. You should have said ... Sophia Loren.

Comment: People also tend to filter the close vote queue by tag so it's likely you'll see the same people closing a lot of questions in particular tags.

Comment: -4 ?? Wow, [such pain](http://imgur.com/gallery/fDUuwuY)!

Comment: @Liviu Ha, minus 4, barely breaking a sweat (or meta has an exagerated voting style, lots of downvotes, but lots of upvotes too)

Comment: In theory even six years old kid can get to 3K and cast close votes. We have couple of teenage moderators. More than that?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Although if you are less than 13 it is [more complicated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61770/how-do-i-use-stack-exchange-if-im-under-13-years-old). On a related note, I believe [we had a teenage moderator at one point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126919/evaluating-the-risks-of-allowing-teen-moderators-on-the-se-network) so age is no barrier

Comment: @RichardTingle it's just matter of hiding your age. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard In theory, there could be robots, succesful scientific experiments on monkeys and genius 2 years old kids. But you didn't get my point, don't you? In practice, most of the close  voters are elders. "Fly, fly, fly, little Clarice"

Comment: @ShadowWizard By the way, Random's nickname may be more idiotic than yours, but at least he's from Ashley Judd. How old are you, really?

Comment: @Liviu I'm 1000 years old, close friend of Gandalf. Happy now? And I can't get your point since there's no point here, just a rant. So what if the age of those who do X is Y?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The first point is that these guys are closing questions for fun or lack of occupation (apparently, it comes with the age). And, if you can think more than the stupid people from your hobbit stories, there's another point: this site tends to be an oligarchy, not a democracy. Just like a child you love Sparta, but, trust me, Athens was better. Personally, I'm against downvotes (Facebook is smarter!), but that's another story, enough talking to you, "Fly, fly, fly, little Clarice!"

Comment: @Liviu I fear Stack Overflow is not the place for you then. Downvotes and closing questions are part of the game, whether you like it or not. If you think people are doing it for fun then it's too bad, but nothing me or anyone else of the stupid people on this planet will say can change your mind. Shadow Wizard, out. P.S. don't think it's a duplicate, voting to reopen for what it's worth.

Comment: Some work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342469/switch-statement-in-c-language [YOU](http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/they_live_wide.jpg) live! I have my glasses now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anyone with 3k reputation can vote to close a question, or vote to reopen the question.

Comment: Oh, nothing about the age? Because I think I have it.

Comment: @Liviu Age is irrelavent, as I said, all that matters is having 3k reputation.

Comment: "You can accept an answer in 3 minutes" : hope they are not that fast!

Answer (score 4):

There is no "council of the elders", per se, but anyone with 3k+ reputation can close or reopen a question, and so you might see some names commonly crop up on the "closed by" box. Age really doesn't matter on SE, we have had some 5 year olds as well as 257 year olds on here, as given by their age box on their profile page

Answer (score 3):

First, you cannot see downvoters.

If you mean people that voted to close the question, they are more experienced users yes because you need 3k reputation to vote and close.

Comment: I said "down" voters (in this context), not "downvoters" (in general).

Comment: @Liviu: It would be more accurate (and less confusing) to say "close voters".

Comment: It's past the 12th night, I think you need a namechange...

Comment: @JonW Can't -_- Have to wait