# Is building up reputation on Stack Overflow to up- and down-vote worth it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, voting

I am a junior developer and visit Stack Overflow multiple times a day to get answers on all sorts of development topics; however I do not have enough reputation to say if comments are helpful or not. I would like to give feedback sometimes that the answers are worthless and need to be downvoted but most are exactly what I needed.

What is the fastest way to get enough reputation to up-/down-vote and is it even worth it to try to build up the reputation to give back to the community?

Comment: The best way is to start reading the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: For your 1st question "What is the fastest way to get enough reputation to up/down vote", see **Six simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast** => http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204/245495

Comment: Yes, another one bites the dust! [The elders](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215270/is-there-a-council-of-the-elders) smell the blood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my question is what is the fastest way to get enough reputation

It is not about how fast you acquire it. But there are many ways to acquire reputation. You can :

- Get upvoted question (+5)
- Get upvoted answer (+10)
- Get accepted edits (+2)
- Get accepted answer (+15)
- Accept helpful answer (+2)

Once you get enough reputation, you will be able to upvote and downvote as you see fit.

> is it even worth it to try to build up the reputation to give back to the community?

This is very opinion based so I cannot give a proper answer. I think it is worth it, if you don't then maybe a community based site like Stack Exchange isn't for you.

Answer (score 2):

> it even worth it to try to build up the reputation to give back to the community?

Yes, of course it is! What is life for if not for free internet points?

> So my question is what is the fastest way to get enough reputation

Here, rep is a rough measure of how much the community trusts you.
. The fastest way to get rep is to answer questions, but if you need a small amount of points fast, say to vote or to comment, just find a bunch of questions that need improvement (say, with badly-formatted code, or with ambiguous statements that lead to down-votes) and improve them.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand I see what you did there.

Comment: @AaronBertrand also I like how I got more rep than the other answer(as of now) than the other answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Yea I just want enough reputation to be able to vote on things that helped me.