# Is there a guideline for appropriate response time from the mods?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I do understand, of course, that being a community driven operation, there's no SLA as such, nor can we demand a reply withing certain amount of time. Patience is the key. And mods are people just like everybody else so life can happen and we ought to respect that.

Having said that, I got a response on my question regarding a ban pretty quickly and even one follow-up. However, the actual question I asked wasn't addressed and after I've asked that, there's been a few weeks with no reply at all.

Keeping the disclaimer in the first paragraph, I feel that my question isn't going to be answered and got buried under a pile of new inputs. It's starting to become crucial to me to get my answer since I'll need to make decision affecting people's employment soon. (As it happens, the information I requested from the mod is vital to who's going to be booted.)

Is there an approximate time when I can safely assume that my follow-up question requesting more information has been disregarded and isn't a part of the pipeline anymore?

Comment: This doesn't directly concern your question here, but be aware that site moderators must abide by the [moderator agreement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement) (which is the same for all SE sites, excepting the specific site name). Depending on the type of information you seek from them, they may not be allowed to provide it to you.

Comment: Was your question perhaps about something the moderator isn't at liberty to share with us users? Ignoring the question might be their way of telling you just that (edit: ifajra beat me to the punch.)

Comment: @Pëkka I can't tell for sure, because the moderator didn't reply. It **could** be a indirect hint. In such case, I'd argue that the clarity of message is way below par and not suitable for moderator role. In fact, it **could** be anything and I'm kind of waiting like an idiot when there's no reply coming, hehe. The claim made in the last reply isn't correct (if the offending party is the one I believe) so even if they aren't allowed to disclose the information **to me** I can still provide the detail **to them**. But it's not possible until they reply... Catch 22...

Comment: Maybe worth following up again to get a clear statement either way?

Comment: @Pëkka Not entirely sure what you meant. Are you saying that it might be a good idea to poke the mod again? Regrettably, I can't do that because the thread is closed for further posts until they get back to be. Also, I can't even find the thread now because I lost all my bookmarks...

Comment: If you're after mods regarding a specific site (and not specifically staff) - bear in mind you're posting on MSE and in neither do you mention which site you're referring to. It's possible the site mods haven't seen your original post or even this post. Have you tried posting on the site specific meta - for the majority of stacks in the network that'll even notify the mods they have a meta post to look at as well.

Comment: @JonClements I have intentionally avoided notifying the mods of the regarded site because I don't want to bother them. As a first step I wanted to see how the community views that in a general case. When that's established, I'll take the next step. That was my idea of approach, at least. To make it structured and properly carried out.

Comment: That's of course if it's moderation related at all. If you're after an answer to a general site question then no one is obliged to answer or follow up on them including mods. All of which can happen for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @JonClements Yes, as the tag implies it's related to the mods. When asking a mod on a reason and details of a suspension, I do believe that they should be obliged to respond and explain. Please see my disclaimer on the level of demandness. There's no SLA as such, of course. However, if you candidate for a mod and get voted in, it's a bit expected to be there. Still, they're people too and life can happen. That's why I'm patient and want to know what, if any, period of time can **safely** be said that *it's too long*.

Comment: @Konrad sites have a different number of moderators and levels of moderation required. It's even possible site moderators haven't checked the global meta around the times you've posted. Posting on the *site specific meta* should be your *first* point of call here.

Comment: Without more specific details I don't see how this question can be answered beyond saying that, like users, community moderators are volunteering their time, and at the moment we cannot even tell whether your question was clear (i.e. with a question mark) or made in the form of a statement.  Is it about a mod message or is it about a Meta Q&A or something else?

Comment: @Konrad I'm just saying that for this specific case - you're asking about a response time for a question posted in a place that no-one may have seen to know you want a response.

Comment: @PolyGeo Good point. I still claim that mods have more expectations on them that *common users* but they're of course normal people with time limitations. Definitely. As for the details, I'd like to provide them but I'm not sure how to access the conversation anymore. I had a link but lost it...

Comment: @JonClements Sorry if I was unclear. I'm asking about the response time for a question I asked to a moderator after I've been suspended. Not **this** question here or on meta but the one that regarded details of my suspension. Direct contact with a mod. I got two replies but the last one contained an incorrect statement (I'm pretty sure) so I asked for clarification on that and since then there was no answer. And I'm about to pick two people to get fired from the team, which will be based partly on that info. Feeling very inconvenient in front of that decision...

Comment: I do not think it appropriate to try and shift responsibility for deciding who gets fired, even only in part, onto a moderator team of volunteers.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm lost now. Who's getting fired in this case? Are you referring to the suspension I got? I'm not following at all... It seems to me like I'm missing some implied info. May I ask you to elaborate?

Comment: @Konrad okay - I've read the history and we don't provide information about users. As the mod who messaged you said it's not that difficult to work out. It's for you to do so - we can't and won't help here.

Comment: You said: "I'm about to pick two people to get fired from the team, which will be based partly on that info. Feeling very inconvenient in front of that decision."

Comment: @Jon while I agree, why let the user wait for weeks, wondering? Why didn't you (or the other mod) replied what you said in the comment to the question when it was asked by the OP here?

Comment: @Shadow because I'm travelling and tapping stuff out with my paws on a mobile is awkward. The OP has their answer (albeit a comment) for now and its hopefully cleared up any questions meta might have instead of guessing. We can address the rest a bit later.

Comment: @Shadow generally a mod will respond to mod messages if it's necessary but we tend to avoid getting dragged into extended discussions if we've said our piece. Even if that's not the case - the number of messages in/out is quite large on SO so unless you notice it fairly promptly they are not too hard to miss as they get pushed out by the more recent ones.

Comment: @JonClements Actually it's **not** easy to figure out because the information provided isn't sufficient. That claim isn't correct, basically. I'd like to see which user accepted my answers and **only** my answers. I believe the mod is mistaken because one of the guys admitted that he accepted my answer **but also** others' answers. I want to verify the claim made by the mod as the poor dude on the team doesn't know how to log in nor find the questions. Keep in mind that **I** might see other things than the mode. So I can't see the info I need. Regrettably.

Comment: @JonClements I have **not** my answer, as I posted a follow-up question. And I find it inappropriate to treat a member with silence because the mod feels like it. I do understand that the mods are people too but the mods did apply for the position and with that comes a bit more responsibility than just hiding behind "we're doing it on our free time". There are elections and there are **many** users willing to help with the burden. As I mentioned before - the claim make my the mod is likely to be wrong. But it's hard to address the mistake if no reply is provided.

Answer (score 14):

I'll talk about the general case, and then this specific one.

When a user is messaged or suspended by a moderator, they can respond once. If a moderator chooses to respond to that, the user can respond once again. All of this is private, but is able to be reviewed by other moderators and SE staff.

Over the years, we've taken [a lot of abuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283725/make-moderator-messages-anonymous#comment919684_283725) in these responses, and heard just about every shaggy dog story you can think of. Frankly, my experience is that any response by a moderator to a complaint about a suspension for voting fraud is pretty much a complete waste of time. When Joe Smith is saying he's being framed by someone when we clearly see two account named Joe Smith, with his same login credentials and from his same location, voting for him 90+% of the time, there's no point in arguing about this.

If we've genuinely made a mistake, and that's been pointed out to us, we will respond and lift suspensions if needed. We don't suspend accounts lightly, though, and we document all evidence that leads to our decision. There's no timeframe on when we'll do this, but that usually takes place within a day or two.

Now to your specific case. We have been instructed by SE staff to not disclose the names of sock puppet accounts or any other private identifying information when someone complains in one of these messages. It is for that reason that I have not provided a response to your latest message.

But, I mean, come on. Prior to this, you had been suspended for voting fraud once, then were warned about this when it happened again. We gave you the benefit of the doubt the second time when you complained it was your employees. Now it happens a *third time*, and you're still trying to say you had no knowledge about this?

I find it very hard to believe that you had no knowledge of this or who was behind it, particularly since the accounts voting for you only asked questions that you immediately answered, they accepted your answers, and then voted exclusively for you. You had an active part in this. This was obvious enough that community members complained and we acted on it. I told you this in my last response, and that's the last you'll hear from me about this.

Comment: seeing the inbox screenshots in the comment you link to i reckon Mods would benefit from profanity filters. unsure of the context of those replies but if they are trying to argue a case and have to use language like that then you might as well consider their case dead

Comment: I was suspended **once** before, in 2012. Not twice as you claim. Please keep your facts straight. And for this case, I believe your claim is incorrect too, because I'm almost sure I know who you're referring to and he claims that he accepted other answers too (not as you say only mine). I'm not disputing the ban - it's over soon anyway. I'm questioning whether you're acting on correct information. I'm asking politely, I'm not nagging. Simply disregarding me in silence and coming with incorrect statements because others abuse and and is in my view unfair. Please check the bans again.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Unless I'm mistaken, Brad only said you were suspended once, and the second incident was just a warning.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara You are **not** mistaken. I misinterpreted the message because it implied that I'm a frequent offender and suggested that the two cases leading to suspension were somehow correlated. I resent such allegation and reacted accordingly. I encourage my students and employees to register and vote when they find something useful - not exclusively on me, of course. On of them says that he upvoted others as well but since I can't know that, I can't confirm it. He's going to be kicked out next week, partly because of this. Thanks for the clarification.