# Mod message templates should not use the first person singular

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, moderator-messages, moderator-templates

[Moderator messages are now signed by “${SITENAME} moderation team” rather than “${USERNAME}, ${SITENAME} moderator”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283725/make-moderator-messages-anonymous/283910#283910). However some moderator message templates still contain “I”, which does not make sense when the message is not signed by a single person.

Please update the templates to use “we” instead of “I”.
For example, in the “self-destruction of useful content” template, “I have placed your account on hold for 1 days while I reach out to you to avoid any further misunderstandings” should be changed to “we have placed your account on hold for 1 days while we reach out to you to avoid any further misunderstandings”.

(Or rather, in this case, to “… on hold for 1 day …”.)

Comment: A co-founder of SE said the S should be big: *... on hold for 1 dayS while ...*

Comment: For the devs: if you keep the singular, remember that you need to handle grammatical gender. In Portuguese, for instance, the verbs will change depending on the gender of the subject. Cf. https://translatewiki.net/wiki/Gender

Comment: @Nemo No, on the number and person but not the gender. Only predicate adjectives that refer to the subject would care about gender. It's like this in all Romance.

Comment: @tchrist I'm Italian, I know. The result is the same: you need gender to translate verbs from English and unless you know all languages in the world you can't guess which English strings won't need it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is live for all sites except International versions of Stack Overflow; we left the old strings in place there to avoid trashing all the translations. Once the new messages are translated, we'll swap those as well.

Comment: will that be on transifex or will be fixed strings?

Comment: Should be on transifex, @gbianchi - both the old and new messages, along with existing translations for the old. Once the new messages have translations (can mostly copy-paste the old translations), we can flip over to using them.

Comment: Ok, so international sites can use traducir to get them up quickly.. If you have a date for that, we could ping everyone on the terminal so everyone can translate them fast enough...

Comment: I'm in no particular hurry; I'll check on it in two weeks, if folks need more time I'll set a reminder for another two weeks.

Comment: Great! I will tell Nicolas when at least most of the sites have them :) thanks :)

Comment: No problem. Hat-tip to Adam Lear for remembering that this would wreak havoc on translations and encouraging me to leave the old strings around for a bit!

Comment: lots of love for him <3

Comment: Most of the message are already translate (at least in spanish). :). So we are safe in that site.. I don't have a clue about the others...